# Passing controller variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code that have a variable and a javascript in controller

```
function detailed_control() {
        $data = array(
            "historical_table" => 1,
            "page_javascript" => "assets/javascript/employeedetail_js.php",  
        );
        $this->load->view('employeedetail_load',$data); 
    }
```

i want in my employeedetail_js javascript to display the $historical_table that have a value of 1

my employeedetail_load is this

```
<?php   
    require_once("assets/includes.php"); 
    require_once($page_javascript); 
    include('assets/template/side.php'); 
    include('assets/template/header_new.php'); 
    include('employeedetail_view.php'); 
    include('assets/template/footer_new.php'); 
?>
```

i can already load my javascript but i want to include my variable $historical_table to my js

Comment: Can we see what is within the `$this->load->view()` function?

Comment: so actually you want to load page_javascript within employeedetail_load, right?

Comment: @A.P. i actually load it already i just want to include the other variable in my javascript

Comment: @Sam see above already posted

Comment: can you show me related code.?

Comment: means you want to pass historical_table variable to that of page_javascript.

Comment: @A.P. yes yes
<?php
                $json = $historical_table;
                $arr = json_decode($json); 
                $arr = (array)$arr; 
            ?>
            alert(<?php $arr[0] ?>); i have that but it alert blank

Comment: I already displayed in my javascript thank you to all

Answer (score 0):

1. first you put  $historical_table  into employeedetail_load view file in a div and can hidden this DIV
2. then in employeedetail_js javascript file you will write a jquery code which extract  $historical_table value from DIV , on onload event or document ready event  employeedetail_js javascript file would be like

   ```
   $(document).load(function(){

   var value = $('#div').val();      
   $('#wher_valu_be_put').val(value);

   });
   ```